# How do I get text messages from broken Samsung Fame

Tags: samsung-galaxy-fame

dropped phone grrr. 
Screen cracked, it lights up but, I can't swipe the screen. I have linked to Kies, got my Contacts over, But, I can't seem to find Texts/sms. Any help greatly appreciated.
Sue
Samsung Galaxy Fame.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this page](http://www.wondershare.com/samsung/samsung-sms-backup.html#part1). It tells you how to backup your SMS messages using Kies. This allows you to load your messages on to a new phone.

An extract:

> Step 3: Click on the Back up/Restore tab. Here you will see a list items that you can backup from your Samsung mobile device.
>
> Step 4: To backup SMS from your Samsung mobile device, click on the checkbox beside Message and click on Backup.
>
> Step 5: Wait until Kies finishes backup Samsung text messages. You can find the backup location at the bottom of the screen.
>
> Step 6: Click on Ok. That's all you have to do to take backup of your SMS from Samsung mobile device.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Otherwise, your answer becomes useless in case the link dies.